# Android deliver json

Tags: android, json

I am developing a project. I write on webpage use jquery:

```
$.post(url, {param: paramstring}, function(result){});
```

`Paramstring` is a json string according to the parameter structure, like `{"action":"get","username":"username"}`.Now I want to run it in android, and add two textview on page to input username and password. There is a register button too. Button listener program is like this:

```
EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
String user = et1.getText().toString();
EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
String password = et2.getText().toString();
// the password should upload after MD5 encryption. this is encryption method. the result is the same with js encryption.
String password_md5 = toMd5(password.getBytes());   
Log.d(TAG, user+"-"+password+"-"+password_md5);
try {
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("action", "get");
params.put("result", "user");
params.put("category", "base");
params.put("username", user);
params.put("password", password_md5);

List<BasicNameValuePair> sendData = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
sendData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param", params.toString()));

System.out.println(params.toString());

request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(sendData,"utf-8"));
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(request.getEntity()));

HttpResponse response= new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request);
String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 

System.out.println(retSrc);

} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

above code return data display login error.I think it is because json structure.`{param:paramstr}` in `$.post()` method is a map. I changed it many times, it is still wrong.

Could you give me some advice? thanks very much!

Comment: i recommend you look on the server side at what is sent by jquery and what is sent by android (and post these results). Then i recommend you use a more standard approach to authentication (http has built-in mechanisms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass each parameter separately and do not need a JSON structure here. The JSON structure used by jQuery is just a method to have a variable number of parameters to the $.post() method.

Instead of this:

```
params.put("action", "get");
params.put("result", "user");
params.put("category", "base");
params.put("username", user);
params.put("password", password_md5);

List<BasicNameValuePair> sendData = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
sendData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param", params.toString()));
```

try this:

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> sendData = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
sendData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "get"));
sendData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("result", "user"));
sendData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category", "base"));
sendData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
sendData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password_md5));
```

You see, instead of the JSON object, the sendData list is used.